# Вывод сайдбара wordpress на все страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

как можно вывести сайдбары на все страницы в wordpress?
Шаблон данную функцию нативно не поддерживает.

Comment: Как вариант скопировать код вывода сайдбара с документа шаблона, где он выводится, и вставить в тот документ шаблона, который вызывается на каждой странице.

Comment: а как скопировать в документ шаблона код?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно зарегистрировать сайдбар в теме https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_sidebar затем вывести его https://wp-kama.ru/function/dynamic_sidebar и тогда можно будет его наполнять в админке

```
function register_my_widgets(){
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => "Правая боковая панель сайта",
        'id' => 'right-sidebar',
        'description' => 'Эти виджеты будут показаны в правой колонке сайта',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets' );


<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'left-sidebar' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```